# Custom Devise views not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am pretty sure I understand how to generate views and route to them with devise but this time I am using devise with 2 different types of models.

I have a 'User' modal and a 'Professional' modal. I have generated both views with

`rails generate devise:views User` & `rails generate devise:views Professional`

I have also set my **routes** to:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'users'}
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'professionals'}
```

For some reason when I visit for example `/users/sign_up` rails is generating **devise/registrations/new** rather than my **users/registrations/new**,

Scopes are all set to true in Devise.rb.

**Is there anything I am not doing right here/missing out?**

*As a side,* When I remove the custom controller route, the views are generating correctly but it then uses the devise controllers and I don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

When you change `devise`'s custom routes you need to move its views from `devise/registrations` to `users/registrations`.

`devise` tries to use your custom controller, but when it can't find appropriate views, it uses defaults.